# How to style datepicker specific elements?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following angular material datepicker sample:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="rangeForm" [rangePicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date" readonly>
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date"
      readonly (dateChange)="onSecondDateChange($event.value)">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is how I see it:
[image]

I want to style:

- `Enter a date range` font color and font size
- `20/10/2020-26/10/2020` font color and font size

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following CSS class **`mat-form-field-label`**, **`mat-date-range-input`** and **`mat-date-range-input-separator`**:

```
.mat-form-field-label {
  color: red;
}
.mat-date-range-input {
  color: blue;
}
.mat-date-range-input-separator {
  color: blue;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Enter a date range" has a class `.mat-form-field-label` and date has class `.mat-input-element` so you need to style it in css.

Comment: second class doesnt do the job

Comment: Maybe your class need to be more specific like for example `input.mat-input-element` or `mat-form-field .mat-input-element`